# PrimeFaces: DefaultCommand.js and DefaultCommand.css required

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to solve a problem I have with a form that works correctly, but when I inspect the downloaded resources through the Network tab, I see that 2 files are required and not found (404 error):

- defaultcommand.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.3.15
- defaultcommand.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.3.15

Please, help me understand the reason behind Primefaces requiring these 2 files, and how to avoid this requirement.

I'm using JSF 2.2 in a Spring 3.1.4 project.

Thanks a lot.

```
<h:form styleClass="smsForm">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="separarArribaMas separarAbajoMas">
        <p:commandButton global="false" action="#{proposicionBean.botonIrPedirTelefono()}" onclick="PF('estadoOperacionDialog').show();" oncomplete="PF('estadoOperacionDialog').hide();" title="#{msg['sms.citainternet.cita.botonConfirmarCita.mensaje']}" styleClass="accion colorPrimario" value="#{msg['sms.citainternet.cita.botonSiguientePasoCita']}" ajax="false"/>
        <p:commandButton global="false" action="#{proposicionBean.botonIrCambiarCitaMobile()}" onclick="PF('estadoOperacionDialog').show();" oncomplete="PF('estadoOperacionDialog').hide();" title="#{msg['sms.citainternet.cita.botonCambiarCita.mensaje']}" styleClass="accion" value="#{msg['sms.citainternet.cita.botonCambiarCita']}" ajax="false"/>
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" onclick="mostrarDialogo();" title="#{msg['mensaje.volver.pagina.inicio']}" styleClass="accion rojo" global="false" value="#{msg['sms.citainternet.botonCancelar']}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="separarArribaMas">
        <p class="ayuda">
            <h:outputFormat value="#{msg['sms.citainternet.cita.citaPropuesta.texto.ayuda']}" escape="false">
                <f:param value="#{msg['sms.citainternet.cita.botonSiguientePasoCita']}"/>
            </h:outputFormat>
        </p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputScript>
            function mostrarDialogo() {
                PF('dialogoDeseaVolver').show();
                $('body').addClass("ocultar");
                $("#wrapper").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
                $("#dialogoDeseaVolverFoco").focus();
            }
        </h:outputScript>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Are your servlet mappings correct (web.xml)?

Comment: Thank you a lot Jasper,
I guess if the servlet mapping wasn't correct, the web pages involucrated would not act correctly. It is not the case. I don't know if I have answerd correctly your question! I don't have much experience working with Spring and JSF.
If you have some doubt about some detail, please don't hesitate to ask me 
Thank you again.

Comment: Search your codebase i feel like `p:defaultCommand` is somewhere in your XHTML or template or something?

Comment: you're exactlty right: I was searching in the wrong place.

Comment: You're exactlty right Melloware. There is a Defaultcommand in the page that has to appear once the first button is pressed. It is placed inside of a  <pm:content> (xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"). This makes my DefaultCommand a Mobile component. I understand this is the reason why the Js and CSS resources are requiered.
I have eliminated the DefaultCommand form the page and the error was eliminated too.
This is not the best solution, but I don't have enough task time to correct the DefaultCommands in the whole project. 
Thanks a lot for your intention to help Jasper and Melloware

Comment: No problem!  glad we could help